# match on a variable that itself depends on matching

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I want to determine whether Program X improved graduation rates at a higher ed institution.  Students self-select into this program, so I'm using propensity score matching (with the `MatchIt` package, if that matters) to create a reasonable control group, controlling for pre-treatment factors.

The complication is that I'd like to treat graduation as *both* an outcome *and* an input.  Students can earn multiple degrees, and they can enter the program at any time.  If a student earned at least one degree *after* entering Program X, I consider that to be an outcome.  But if the student earned at least one degree *before* entering Program X, I consider that to be an input and want to match on it.  (Students who have already earned a degree may be more likely to sign up for Program X than students who haven't.)

For students who participated in Program X, things are easy: I can check any degrees the student earned against the term when the student entered the program.  But control students are more difficult.  Essentially, I want to match on "did the control student earn any degrees before the term when the *treated* student entered Program X?".  In other words, I don't know which of a control student's degrees would count as inputs until I've already identified a possible match with a treated student.

What would be the best way to proceed?  Can I use propensity score matching at all?  Do I need to write a custom distance measure?

Comment: Consider a marginal structural model. See [Robins et al (2000)](http://doi.org/10.2307/3703997), [Vandecandelaere et al (2016)](http://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2016.1155146), or [Thoemmes & Ong (2016)](http://doi.org/10.1177/2167696815621645) for introductions. This involves modeling it as a longitudinal process, where at each time point the student can be in the program or not and have earned a degree or not.

Comment: This is helpful; thanks!  If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.